# Algorithm to make nested data structure from a table in Java

Tags: java

In my database I have a table which is show in below. Now I want to make a nested data structure to draw on a view by an algorithm to *transfer data* from table to this

```
Tables -> Seats -> Rounds -> Dish_names

Note that -> stands for 'contain'
```

Could anyone have a clean way to do this in Java. Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you want exactly, but if you want a nested Java Object (entity) to correspond to the table, read on:

Since **Tables** contain **Seats** contain **Rounds** contain **Dish_names**, you start from the innermost entity (Dish):

```
Public class Dish{
  private int id; // an id  
  private String dish_name;
  // getters and setters
}
```

Your `Round`s contain the `Dish`es

```
 Public class Round{
      private int id; // an id  
      private List<Dish> dishes;
      // getters and setters
    }
```

Your `Seat`s contain the `Round`s

```
Public class Seat{
      private int id; // an id  
      private List<Round> rounds;
      // getters and setters
    }
```

And finally you `Table`s contain the `Seat`s

```
 Public class Table{
      private int id; //  
      private List<Seat> seats;
      // getters and setters
    }
```

Comment: Yes that're entities, but I need to fill out the data from the table

Answer (score 0):

The class structure as you mentioned.

```
class Table
    List<Seat> seats = ArrayList<>();

class Seat
    List<Round> rounds = ArrayList<>();

class Round
    List<Seat> seats = ArrayList<>();

class Dish
```

For instance, using immutable objects:

```
public class Table {
    public final int id;
    public final List<Seat> seats = ArrayList<>();

    public Table(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

For construction of unique entity objects you need to map the keys to the entity object.

```
Map<Integer, Table> tablesById = new HashMap<>();
Map<Integer, Seat> seatsById = new HashMap<>();
Map<Integer, Round> roundsById = new HashMap<>();
Map<String, Dish> dishesByName = new HashMap<>();
```

> With a bit more effort, but cleaner result one could make `Set<Table>`
>   etcetera.

Now you can traverse the database table and check

```
Table table = new Table(resultSet.getInt("Table"));
table = tablesById.putIfAbsent(table.id, table);
// Now table is a maybe already existing table of the map.

Seat seat = new Table(resultSet.getInt("Seat"));
seat = seatsById.putIfAbsent(seat.id, seat);
table.seats.add(seat);

...
```

The method `putIfAbsent` exists since java 8. In earlier java you can `get` and only when it does not exist `put` a new Table.